# Should my $PATH be returning anything RVM related?

Tags: ruby, macos, shell, zsh

I am running the command

```
echo $PATH
```

which is returning the following information containing RVM

> /Users/RAI/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/RAI/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/RAI/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/RAI/.rvm/bin

Should this command only return the following?

> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Note that I am currently using on My Zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should this command only return the following?

No, it returns what's been set. Look at your `~/.zshrc` file for starters but there are also other places that `$PATH` can be set.

Comment: Thanks, that helped clear any confusion that I had regarding what I had returned within my environment.